# Accessing $@ (the file name of the target of the rule) outside of the rule

Tags: shell, variable, make

Suppose I want a program (say, `Some_Command`) to obtain the name of the target as one of its parameter  (passed with flag `-p`) from the command-line, and that I want the parameters with which the command is called to be contained in a single variable (say, `COMMON_ARG`) that I can re-use.
[I know](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Automatic-Variables.html) I can access the target's name using `$@`, but I believe this variable has a value only *from inside the rule*. Is there any way to defer the evaluation of that variable?

Typically, I would like to have

```
COMMON_ARG:= "-p $@"
foo:bar
    Some_Command $(COMMAND_ARG) $< -o $@
```

so that `Make bar` calls

```
Some_Command -p foo bar -o foo
```

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2403881

Comment: The := operator is completely non-portable. It has been introduced in 1986 by SunPro Make as conditional macro assignment. GNU make much later introduced := for something different that is not needed in a standard compliant make, since you always can prevent expansion on use by typing `$$(NAME)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you declare a variable with `=` (instead of `:=`), it will be [recursively expanded](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Flavors.html#Flavors) wherever it’s used, and not when it’s declared. Thus

```make
COMMON_ARG = -p $@
foo: bar
        Some_Command $(COMMAND_ARG) $< -o $@
```

will expand `$@` inside the recipe, giving the effect you’re after.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I thought I've tried, but as it turns out, `COMMON_ARG` was used in a _second_ variable that was using `:=` instead of `=`. So _all the variables_ that relates to this one have to not be recursively expanded. Thanks a lot for pointing that out, it greatly helped me.